# How to get the list of policies assigned to a user using boto3 for an aws profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, aws-cli, boto3

I am still in the learning phase of boto3 and I can't seem to figure out the basics as to get the list of policies assigned to a user using boto3 for an aws profile?

For example:

```
>> import boto3
>> client=boto3.client('iam')
>> client.get_user()
```

Here, `client.get_user()` doesn't give me the policy attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but what you want is:

For inline policies:

```
inline_user_policies = client.list_user_policies(UserName=user_name)
```

For managed policies:

```
managed_user_policies = client.list_attached_user_policies(UserName=user_name)
```

Comment: do you know how to do the same thing for roles instead of users?  Have yet to find answer in boto3 docs.